# convert string array to integer array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an array:

```
var endFlowArray = new Array;
for (var endIndex in flowEnd) { // <- this is just some numbers 
    for (var i in dateflow) { // <- same thing 
        var check = $.inArray(flowEnd[endIndex], dateflow[i]);
        if (check >= 0) {
            endFlowArray.push(i);
            flowEnd[endIndex] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I convert a string array of:

```
["286", "712", "1058"]
```

to integer array like:

```
[286, 712, 1058]
```

Comment: It's an easy fix. `.push(+i)` or `.push(parseInt(i))`. Simply converting a string to an integer.

Comment: `my endFlowArray came up with something like this` You need to explain this statement. How did it "come up"? Are you using a javascript debugger? alert? Something else?

Comment: is `dateflow` an array of strings or numbers?

Comment: Kevin B solve it BUT i still need to know whar happend

Comment: Show the creation of the strings in dataflow and you have your answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strings in the console are symbolized by wrapping them in quotes. By that fact, we can assume that `i` is a string. Convert it to an integer and it will no longer be a string and no longer have those quotes.

```
endFlowArray.push(+i);
```

Your "numbers" in `flowEnd` and `dateFlow` are actually strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 172):

```
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(Number);
```

Comment: Short and sweet way to typecast.

Answer (score 4):

To convert entire array's data type we can use `map()`:

```
let numberArray = stringArray.map(Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let numberArray = stringArray.map(el=>parseInt(el))
```

Comment: That gets the job done, but some formatting wouldn't hurt! :)